# mvc where to format strings in controller or in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC with C#. I need to format strings in different ways. Can you please guide which place is best to do that, control actions or aspx page ?

Comment: can you tel us more about your problem

Comment: Need your code and some description of the scenario :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formating data which will be display to user, always the best choice is View. It is by [definition of MVC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

> A view requests from the model the information that it needs to
>   generate an output representation to the user.